# Mini Map not showing in GTA 5/GTA Online after ill Gotten gains update

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

As the title says my mini map is not getting displayed in gta 5/gta online, actually only the roads are not getting displayed, the shops and other stuff are normal. This happened only after the ill gotten gains DLC update.
Anyone facing this issue ? If yes any solution ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pause the game, go to `Settings`, click `Display`, and check if `Radar` is set to `on`. If it isn't, then set it to `on`. The reason you can only see blips (shops, players, mission icons) may be because `Radar` is set to `Blips`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have to change your settings for the radar in the display settings.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out so if your mini maps not showing what you do is you go into your phone go into any job and then once it loads exit the job and your mini map should show up on your screen hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

the same happened to me, but I could not pause, open my phone, or pull out guns. The only thing than I could do was close the application and join back. It was happening to everyone in my heist. By the way I am on PS4.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was I had to buy a garage and it reappeared after the cutscene just try doing something with a cutscene hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

It happens because your save game is corrupted. I can mod my save so I can look at the block address. No other options, just delete it and get over it and move on! The online character is tied to your GTA 5 save game because it uses the same character model with a different appearance and reads certain attributes from your GTA 5 save.

In short,

- Clear all saves (keep profile)
- Play first mission
- Save
- Fixed online & off!

Now you can browse buy cars & cheer up 
Hope it helps!